# invoking nested array in hash and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this piece of code where after element's class being retrieved a call to a nested array in hash is made using the 'class' value as a key.
It works fine in webkit and firefox but the if statement crashes in IE it doesn't recognize the given objects!

```
<div class="menu groups">
....
</div>
```

js

```
var menusMaxStatus = {'groups' : [70,false], 'attendees' : [40,false] }

var classes = currMenu.attr('class').substr(5);

if( menusMaxStatus[classes] &&  menusMaxStatus[classes][1]){
    normalizeMenu(classes,currSection);
    return;
}
```

I'm also using jQuery

Would you show me the proper syntax?

console says

```
'attr(...)' is null or not an object
'menusMaxStatus[...]' is null or not an object
```

Comment: Please show normalizeMenu and explain what you mean by crashes in IE and what is currSection? Can you make a jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: By "crashes" I mean it doesn't work and as far as normalizeMenu it isn't invoked at all because in IE it doesn't enter the if's body

Comment: 'attr(...)' is null or not an object
'menusMaxStatus[...]' is null or not an object

Comment: Please explain the context of your problem. What is it you're trying to achieve? Is `currMenu` a jQuery object? I.e.: does `$(currMenu).class([...]` have the same result?

Comment: Also, you should read [ask]; it will help you get better answers to your questions more quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got it IE was returning additional classes from jQuery UI and thus key to the hash element is incorrect.
Sorry for the trouble, I didn't provide the needed details after all.